What exactly was Teddy KGB's tell that Mike identified?
In the last poker game of the movie Rounders (1998), through inner dialogue we learn that Mike identified one of Teddy KGB's tells.  He said it involved eating the Oreos.  But was it something specific about the way he ate the Oreo?  I would think it would be something more specific than just simply [Teddy eats Oreo = Teddy has a great hand].

Over on Poker SE -> https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6263/what-is-teddy-kgbs-tell

It was the fact that he was chewing slowly, according to the script. Teddy compulsively wolfs down Oreos throughout the first half of the game. Matt spots that he split the Oreo in half when he had a bad hand, and then chewed his Oreo 'thoughtfully'. Matt figures that this change in behaviour must indicate that he now has a good hand.

Matt puts his hand on his stack.
Matt (V.O.): Like a fighter when it's too late to win on the scorecards, I'm looking for that one haymaker that'll turn things around. Thing is, the harder you to try for that one punch, the more it slips away. But I have a hand, and it's time to bet it all right now.
Matt is about to act when Teddy puts an Oreo in his mouth and slowly chews.
Matt stares at Teddy's mouth. [HE PAUSES].
ANGLE ON: Teddy's mouth as he slowly chews.
Matt removes his hand from his stack.
MATT: I'm gonna check.

Matt explicitly lays it out for us toward the end of the game.

Matt slams his hand on the table.
MATT: (V.O.) Most guys would've gone on chewing slowly till they were dead broke. Teddy spots his own tell after one hand, he's
that good. But no one's immune to getting a little rattled.


I feel like this ending was kind of the weakest part of the movie.  I didn't really get it until I played poker for a decade or two but when KGB says, "you tricked me!" I can't help but think, "Uh yeah. Isn't that the whole point of poker? What game did you think you were playing?"

@JimmyJames reminds me of a conversation between I think Phil Helmuth and Tony G at the table where Phil Helmuth accuses Tony G of lying (about not seeing his hand before going all in pre-flop) and his reply is very similar.

@Michael - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=trYm4vTT2ec

@Michael There are some rules against lying in these tournaments. But even if it were illegal, it would be a matter of proving that and then getting an official to rule on it. I was (coincidentally) just listening to something about WSOP rule enforcement being lax the other day.

@JimmyJames I assume you are referring to the kerfluffle over the eventual winner basically using a solver on a computer with his rail between hands...

@Michael Yep that's it exactly.
